# Which Versions of Magento 2 are latest till date?

Tags: version

I was looking for latest and stable versions of Magento 2. Is there a proper guide which version is latest in different series like 2.4 or 2.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento latest version

you can download below link.

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.3.0 is latest version. you can download from Magento
https://magento.com/tech-resources/download